# Basic steps for setting up file upload on website

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload

I'm trying to set up a file upload for my website but I'm not sure what I'd need to get this to work overall. I'm trying to use [Jquery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) but I can't seem to get the files to upload to my server. It looks like I might need something else to get it to run but I'm not sure what. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like that plugin has [documentation on setting it up](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup).  Did you read the PHP instructions?  If so, what did not work?  I don't think your question is specific enough; it is unlikely someone will be able to guess why the files are not uploading to your server without more info.  Please elaborate.

Comment: All works fine, even there is php script - you need to set it up properly, if you will use (probably) php for uploads...

Comment: Sorry about that, I guess it was intended to be vague (Rob W did a pretty good job of answering what I wanted). I think I solved the problem, I found a section pointing to the server-side upload handler. Now I just have to figure out what that is...

Answer (score 0):

There are three "sides" to a file upload.

First is client-side: You need to have a form that can upload files (so you need to set the `enctype` attribute of your `form` element, and set your `action` to `post`).

Second is server-side: You need something that can handle the file upload. Assuming you're using a server with PHP, you can access the file via `$_FILES['filename']`. Google has a vast array of example for handling file uploads.

Third is server-side (again) - your server must allow file uploads. Not only must it allow file uploads, but it restricts the size of the file that can be uploaded (php config).

However, it looks like jquery file upload has a PHP file handler.

Comment: So what you're saying is that jquery file upload handles the first two "sides" and then I need to make sure that my server size properly handles the uploads?

Answer (score -1):

I will sugest you use dreamweaver its easy to use expecially to upload files to the web n you can also see the steps needed in its help content. or you may download an ftp uploader

Comment: Well this is for use from the website. Obviously I'm able to submit files to my own ftp server or else I wouldn't be able to even view the form.